# Quick way to fix spelling mistakes in a jetbrains IDE?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a fast way to fix spelling mistakes in jetbrains? A keyboard shortcut or some setting to change the menu?

If I have a typo in a word it requires **4 clicks/large mouse movements to fix!**. This is incredibly slow and painful.

1. Right click on the word
2. Go to "spelling" on the menu
3. Click on "Typo: change to"
4. Click one of the suggestions in the new menu

[image: stage 1]
[image: stage 2]

The standard method(browser, sublime, MS Word, etc...) requires 2 steps.

1. right click
2. click on the suggestion.

Also in the standard way of doing it your mouse is already in the correct location so you dont need to move it across the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your cursor on the misspelled word, you should be able to press alt-enter, then press enter, then either click on the corrected spelling or use the arrow keys and enter to select the correct spelling.

Comment: This does not work. It opens the following menu: https://www.dropbox.com/s/79jqahoetn05byu/Screenshot%202016-08-02%2013.08.02.png?dl=0

Comment: @Jakobovski huh. Really? Alt-enter should open a menu with "change to", "save to dictionary" etc., with "change to" highlighted; pressing enter with "change to" highlighted should then open another menu with suggestions for the correct spelling. Make sure your mouse isn't over the area where the menu appears.

Comment: Is it possible to enter all curly underline words in a dictonary with one action?